# Program a JavaScript loop to take out characters

Tags: javascript

Suppose I've this code:

```
XBGa_AHjhdjsDjk_sad/safasdf_Sdfsdfasfdsa
```

I want to take `XBGa_AHjhdjsDjk_sad` out of this. I want to run a loop in JavaScript which appends each character to a variable and if the character is `/` the loop is terminated.

How do I do that?

Comment: This has nothing to do with either `html`, `jquery` or `dom`. Removed those tags.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = 'XBGa_AHjhdjsDjk_sad/safasdf_Sdfsdfasfdsa';
var spl = str.split('/');
var result = spl[0]; // This will be equal to XBGa_AHjhdjsDjk_sad
```

I am not sure if you mean that you want the first or second part of the string, but you get the idea. `spl` becomes an array after executing the split method.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution can be done much simpler than looping through each character

```
var old_val = 'XBGa_AHjhdjsDjk_sad/safasdf_Sdfsdfasfdsa';

var new_val = old_val.substring(old_val.indexOf('/')+1); //this will find the "/" and take the string after it
```

Comment: @MehulMohan don't be lazy and ungrateful. You were given a solution - free help to your problem, if you want a fiddle make one.